# Affine connection restricted to open sets

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I am struggling to understand why in the following highlighted part of the second image (the previous image showing how the notion of a connection is introduced in my notes on Riemannian Geomety) : [image]

[image]

we have that $\nabla_{e_i}(e_j)$ makes sense. Namely in the previous page (first image), $\nabla$ takes two vector fields and returns a third, but these vector fields are globally defined, whereas our local frame is a collection of vector fields on some open subset $U \subset \mathcal{M}$. I am guessing that there must be a natural operator $\nabla \restriction U$ that takes vector fields defined on $U$ and returns vector fields on $U$, and this operator must be such that it coincides with $\nabla$ when its inputs are globally defined vector fields restricted to $U$. I also suppose that we could show such an operator exists and is unique via using bump functions, but I am not sure how this would work for any random open $U \subset \mathcal{M}$.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: $(U,\nabla|_U)$ makes sense. There is a standard but important result saying that $(\nabla_VX)|_U = {(\nabla|_U)}_{V|_U}X|_U$. Unfortunately, the author seems not to worry about this in this early pages about affine connexions. This is also implied by the following: $\nabla_VX$ at $p$ only depends on $V(p)$ and on the $1$-jet of $X$ at $p$, so extending $X$ and $V$ by $0$ away from $p$ thanks to a bump function will give you the desired result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this point get frequently ignored in differential geometry texts. In fairness, such a restriction result should be a lemma. Try to prove it, the existence of such a restriction is a nice  exercise. Ideally, one should define connections in terms of the sheaf of local vector fields. But introducing the sheaf terminology this early is frequently unfeasible. BTW, there is a similar issue with Riemannian metrics which are frequently defined in terms of pairs of global vector fields. There is a good chance that your notes are sloppy in this regard as well.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think I resolved the issue by proving the lemma , essentially by first showing that given vector fields $X,Y$ agreeing on some open neighbourhood of a point $p$, for any section $s$, $\nabla_{X}(s)  = \nabla_{Y}(s)$ on some neighbourhood of $p$, the same sort of thing holds for sections $s_1,s_2$ agreeing locally, then I define $\nabla \restriction U$ so that it has the desired property , and show it is well-defined via the locality lemma I first mentioned.